# I2C function for PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, simulation, proteus

I wrapped a function for I2C initialization on [PIC18F26J50](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en534041) and it happens to be somewhat like this:

```
void i2c_init()
{
                                          //Initialize pins as input for I2c
    SSPSTAT=0x80;
    SSPADD=0x18;                                     //100khz baud rate
    SSPCON1=0x28;                                    // Master mode in I2c.
    SSPCON2=0x00;
    TRISBbits.TRISB4=1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB5=1;
}
```

But when I burn the code into the PIC in simulation it does not work properly. Is there anything wrong with this function? It is supposed to show a clock running at 100kHz.

This is the new code:

```
void main(void)
{
    OpenI2C(MASTER, SLEW_ON);                         // Initialize I2C module
    SSPADD = 9;                                       //400kHz Baud clock(9) @16MHz
                                                      //100kHz Baud clock(39) @16MHz
    i2c_init();
    while(1)
    {
        StartI2C();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you testing this on the simulator?

Comment: Really, hard coded constants without documentation of what the bits mean!?  No thanks.

Comment: Um, why do you think this code should show a 100kHz clock? Unless you're actually transmitting something, the I2C lines will be idle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, initializing the I2C controller wont make any clock nor signal appear on the bus until you start a transaction.

Comment: So inside a while loop if i just endlessly transmit write/read signal,i trust i would enable me to see the signals on simulation right?

Comment: Yes, just send "START" conditions endlessly, and you should will see a signal, at least in real life. I don't know how your simulator is supposed to handle this.

Comment: Hi     tried with this new code still the simulation does not works.
void main(void)
{
    
//********************************************
OpenI2C(MASTER, SLEW_ON);// Initialize I2C module
                                                      SSPADD = 9; //400kHz Baud clock(9) 
//100kHz Baud clock(39) 
                                                          i2c_init();
                                                           while(1)
{

    StartI2C();
                                                                                                                                 }
   
}

Comment: I believe StartI2C() only put the I2C controller in a  neutral state. The start condition is the first data transmission you have to send on the I2C bus. As far as i know, Microchip  doesn't provide high level functions for that, you will have to work with the i2c control bits.  Here is a decent tutorial: http://www.ermicro.com/blog/?p=2157. You might also have a better chance on the microchip forum http://www.microchip.com/forums/f10.aspx

Comment: Hey i tried that and it certainly improved my understanding.And i edited the code and inserted a while condition as shown above to see the scl and sda pulses..but in vain. i tried with the oscilloscope but in vain.Did i miss any thing in the configuration?i cross checked many times but i could  not find any faults..i did bread board connections too..but i2c is not on board now.:) i would appreciate your valuable inputs